# If cell equals 0 then change that value to the one from adjacent cell

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with a single sheet that contains a table with 3 columns(years) and as many rows as there are months in a year.

Each cell under those headers has an integer number, usually between 0-10.

I'm trying to use a function that checks whether the cell this function is assigned to is equal to 0. If so, replace that 0 with a value from adjacent cell.

Formula: `=IF(C11=0,C10,"")`

For example, if there are two cells we're interested in C10 and C11.

`C10 = 6
C11 = 0`

If cell C11 has this formula, then it should replace 0 with 6.

Right now it doesn't change anything. Value in C11 remains 0. Why is that?

Comment: What you are describing is a circular reference and is not possible with formulas.  You can not reference the cell in which the formula is found.  You can do this in another cell then copy and paste the value manually, or you will need vba.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate the entire range alongside and then use formula in that copy table.

You cannot reference the cell you are entering formula into within it's own calculation. Your formula is fine otherwise.

Comment: That's what I decided to do - duplicate the entire table and reference that in the IF function. Thanks.